# How to enable setting of Windows 2012 for accessing by Remote server administration tool

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I want to use Remote Server Administration Tool on Window 7/10 to manage Server that is not under domain it's stand alone server. I have a specific account that has administrator privilege on the server. But I can not access from my PC. 
Do you know where I should change configuration of GPO/firewall/enabling services on Windows server 2012? Please kindly advice me.

Environment:
Server: Windows 2012 server(stand alone server)
Client: Windows 7/10

Answer (score 0):

If the firewall is on you will need to allow access through the firewall. You can used the following command to do this

`Netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=“remote administration” new enable=yes`